# How do I share a connection from an iPhone to Ubuntu?

Tags: wireless, iphone, tether

I would like to share my 3g connection from my iPhone with my computer. I made it worked using usb on ubuntu 12.04 but since I updated to 12.10 (my bad) now it says : "device not managed".

I tried a lots of things, pdanet and so on but when my computer connect to the mobile I am unable to browse the net even if the connection is on. It seems like an @ or routing issue and I can't fix it by myself.

If you have any solution, please help me !